# Android bitmap scale banner image to portrait

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, picasso

I'm pulling in images from a cms and they are banner style (width = 900, height = 250). I have to use them in a fullscreen portrait mode, so naturally they are badly distorted. I've tried a lot of different things with xml, resizing bitmaps, picasso transforms etc..but not sure what else to try at this point. The only time I've been able to maintain quality is by centercropping, but that isn't an option. I need the image to maintain its aspect ratio. Is this even possible to do without sacrificing the aspect ratio? The images aspect ratio 1.7 while the desired is 0.5625 on my galaxy s5.

Edit for more details:

This is a proprietary project so I can't include the images I'm using but they are banner style. They are being used in an imageview that is `screenSizeHeight - toolbarHeight` and `screensizewidth / 1.2`.

this is how I'm trying to resize the bitmap. It's just centercropping though and is much too large.

```
    public static final Bitmap scaleAndCropBitmapByPixelDimensions(final Context context, final Bitmap sourceBitmap, final int targetWidth, final int targetHeight)
{
    try
    {
        if (context != null && sourceBitmap != null)
        {
            int srcWidth = sourceBitmap.getWidth();
            int srcHeight = sourceBitmap.getHeight();

            float targetAspectRatio = (float)targetWidth / (float)targetHeight;
            float srcAspectRatio = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;

            int scaleWidth = targetWidth;
            int scaleHeight = targetHeight;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;


            if (srcAspectRatio < targetAspectRatio)
            {
                scaleWidth = targetWidth;
                scaleHeight = (int)((float)(1 / srcAspectRatio) * (float)scaleWidth);
                x = 0;
                y = (scaleHeight - targetHeight) / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                scaleHeight = targetHeight;
                scaleWidth = (int)((float)srcAspectRatio * (float)scaleHeight);
                x = (scaleWidth - targetWidth) / 2;
                y = 0;
            }


            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sourceBitmap, scaleWidth, scaleHeight, true);
            Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, x, y, targetWidth, targetHeight);
            return croppedBitmap;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error scaling and cropping bitmap", ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Setting up the bitmap transform

```
@Override
            public Bitmap transform(Bitmap sourceBitmap) {
                i_bitmap = Utils.scaleAndCropBitmapByPixelDimensions(mContext,sourceBitmap,targetWidth,targetHeight);


                if (sourceBitmap != i_bitmap) {
                    // Same bitmap is returned if sizes are the same
                    sourceBitmap.recycle();
                }

                return i_bitmap;


            }
```

imageview xml

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="center"       />
```

and loading the image with picasso
    `Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(url)
            .transform(transformation)
            .into(getBg());`

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the desired aspect ratio is the opposite of the actual ratio, one thing you can is to simply rotate the banner images (-90º or +90º).

Of course, this is a very naive suggestion. Maybe if you give more details about the contents to be displayed or any other constraints, we'll be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: made an edit with more info. Wouldn't rotating make the image sideways or am I misunderstanding what you're suggesting?